# MySQL WorkBench Stored Procedure Question

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Can't figure out how to make mysql display the stored procedure result. Can't use table_name.column_name when calling the procedure. So the procedure doesn't know what table in the schema it should call? 
 Trying to take an average of a numeric column called cateringID in a table called package. This table has `NULL` values several rows. Need to do this as a procedure. First converted all the NULLs values in cateringID field to numeric value  of `0.0` in the procedure. Then took the resulting average of this field in the procedure. Then tried to call the procedure. But when trying to extract the average value of the cateringID field that is in the stored procedure, get `NULL` value?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE average_numeric_nulls(IN pPackageID INT, IN pCateringID DEC) 
BEGIN

DECLARE pCateringID DECIMAL(5,4);     
DECLARE catID DECIMAL(5,4);  

SELECT IF(pCateringID IS NULL, 0.0000, FORMAT(pCateringID, 4))  
INTO catID
FROM package
WHERE packageID = pPackageID;

SELECT(AVG(catID)) AS 'Replaced NULLS' FROM package;

END// 
DELIMITER ; 

CALL average_numeric_nulls(@packageID, @cateringID);
```

The pPackageID and pCateringID parameters represent the first two fields from an existing package table. ie.

pPackageID = packageID the PK in the package table. packageID is a numeric integer
pCateringID = cateringID the FK in the package table. cateringID is a mix of numeric integers and NULLs. Need to take the average of this column but must replace NULLs with 0.0 first.

So the procedure is supposed to read the value of the packageID from package table, pass this packageID value to the pPackageID variable in the procedure, then replace all pCateringID values if they are NULLs with the value 0.0000. So the average of the resulting cateringID column in the package table can be taken.

example package table

packageID cateringID packageName
001       NULL        A
002       NULL        B
003       001         C
004       002         D
005       003         E

Result ouput: 
Replaced NULLS 
NULL

Comment: *the procedure is supposed to read the value of the packageID from package table, pass this packageID value to the pPackageID variable in the procedure, then replace all pCateringID values if they are NULLs with the value 0.0000. So the average of the resulting cateringID column in the package table can be taken.* No, your SP did absolutely another action. It formats pCateringID parameter according to provided pPackageID presence in the table then displayes it.

Answer (score 0):

> So the procedure is supposed to read the value of the packageID from package table, pass this packageID value to the pPackageID variable in the procedure, then replace all pCateringID values if they are NULLs with the value 0.0000. So the average of the resulting cateringID column in the package table can be taken.

This can be performed by one single query:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(AVG(COALESCE(cateringID, 0)), 4) AS avg_cateringID
FROM package
-- WHERE ...;
```

If you need to get average for some definite rows set then add according WHERE.

If you need to do it in SP form then

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE average_numeric_nulls(IN pPackageID INT, IN pCateringID DEC) 
SELECT FORMAT(AVG(COALESCE(cateringID, 0)), 4) AS avg_cateringID
FROM package
-- WHERE ...;
```

Use SP parameters in WHERE clause (or remove them if they not needed).

Comment: Thank you so much Akina.  I can't believe how insanely simple that was. I just couldn't get my mind wrapped around how to do this is a single query (hence having to default to an incredibly complex & unnecessary procedure)